# Error C2873: float_t is not a member of "global namespace"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm migrating a Visual C++ 6.0 project to Visual Studio 2013. After solving many issues I'm stucked at the following error in `cmath` header file from windows sdk :

`Error C2873: float_t is not a member of "global namespace"`

The line is :

`using _CSTD float_t; using _CSTD double_t;`

Do you know any solution for this ?

Comment: How are you including the library? Maybe [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/5207/) can give you a hint.

Comment: A workaround would be `typedef float float_t`;

Comment: Looks like you may need to `#define FLT_EVAL_METHOD 0` prior to including `<cmath>`. Or include `<cfloat>` prior to `cmath`, I'm not sure.

Comment: cmath.h from Windows SDK?

Comment: Thank you guys for the tips. In my `.cpp` file I've included `<cmath>`. I've tried @VioletGiraffe workaround but I have the same errors. I can't explain why the errors are in the windows sdk header file and not in my `.cpp` file.  It could be a project configuration issue ?

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, the compiler flags the errors in `cmath.h` from Windows SDK  and not in my `.cpp` file.

Comment: But there is no such file as cmath.h in Windows SDK...

Comment: @SergeyA You're right, is not a header file. I didn't look carefully. The actual file where the compiler flags the errors is : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cmath`

Comment: I've noticed that the compiler flags error every line that has `using _CSTD`